# Does a context switch occurs when an interrupt is fired?

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel, x86, operating-system

A process's virtual address space contains 1 GB of kernel space:

[image]

Now I assume that this 1 GB of kernel space points to data and code related to the kernel (including the Interrupt Descriptor Table (IDT)).

Now let's say that some process is being executed by the CPU, and this process made a system call (fired the interrupt `0x80` (int `0x80`)). What will happen is that the CPU will go to the IDT and execute the interrupt handler associated with the interrupt number `0x80`.

Now will the CPU stays in the current process, and execute the interrupt handler from the kernel space of the current process (so no context switching occurs)?

Comment: Interrupts don't cause context switches. They're served within the context of whatever's running at the moment.

Comment: See this [Context switch in Interrupt Handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4732409/1928852) question.

Comment: Context switching is a software concept so when exactly contexts switch depends on the software and how it defines what context switch is. The x86 has hardware support for a "task switching" mechanism, but it's not used for context switching in modern Linux kernels.

Comment: @PSkocik: But can I say that interrupt will possible to trigger scheduler, which thus cause context switching happen?

Comment: @RossRidge: If I define context switching as changing which process will own the cpu then can I say that interrupt will possible to trigger scheduler, which thus cause context switching happen?